# How to Create culster in elasticsearch 6.2

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

```
   Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", false)
            .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
            .put("cluster.name", "TESTCULSTER").build();

    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));

  //  ClusterAdminClient clusterAdminClient = client.admin().cluster();


    ClusterHealthResponse healths = client.admin().cluster().prepareHealth().get();
    String clusterName = healths.getClusterName();
    System.out.println(clusterName);
```

I am geeting this error
Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{zJ52yLDcR82UUQ7j-oxm6w}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to connect to an elasticsearch via Java, right?

1. I suggest to use the HTTP transport (port 9200) rather than 9300
2. You enabled "sniffing", that means Java client will try to connect to each nodes directly, be sure communication is possible
3. Be sure you can `curl` your ES node from where you run the Java client

Comment: Hi @Thomas, Yes I want to connect an elasticsearch via Java.
I have changes the port but still getting error.

I

Comment: have wrote like this. 
`Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", "NavalTest").build();
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9200))
                .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9200));`

Comment: can you ``curl localhost:9200`` fine from where you run the Java?